# Javascript local variable is overriding global variable?

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables, local-variables

```
var x = 3;

if(1==1){
    if(2==2){
        var x= 5;       
    }
}

document.write(x); // outputs 5
```

So I was running some tests to understand the concept of local and global scope better. I thought declaring `x` with **keyword** `var` creates a local variable and ignores any variable with the same name in the parent scope. By ignore, I mean how I can change the variable `x` without affecting the same variable in the scope above it. But apparently my understanding of the definition of js variables is wrong. could please explain why it behaves so?

Comment: You understanding is correct, but since you are inside a if and not inside a function, both of your `x` have the same scope

Comment: conditions with `if`, and loops like `for` or `while` don't create their own scope in JS

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curly braces (`{...}`) does not create scope for `var` in JavaScript. So when you declare any variable (`x`) with the same name (`x`) in side `{...}` it does not create any new variable but actually override the previously declared variable.

Answer (score 2):

`var` declares a local variable inside a function. For block-scope local variables, use `let`.

```
var x = 3;
if(1==1){
    if(2==2){
        let x = 5;
    }
}
console.log(x); // prints 3
```